# Move the focus of the page to the clicked element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a functionality like on Wikipedia there are outline of the article at the top and when I click on it, it will take me to the clicked element in the same page, I have tried to search it but I'm having trouble in interpreting it so I could get the exact search, can anybody please help me. Here is the code, the $myvalues[1] in the second foreach is the name of the div and $cat_name[1] is the href attribute.

```
<div class="bran-cat">
            <h2>Category</h2>
            <div class="cat-list">
                <?php
                    foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $cat_name){
                        echo "<a href='#".$cat_name[1]."' class='cat-anchor'>".">".$cat_name[1]."</a> <br>";
                    }
                    //$sel_cat= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ");
                ?>
            </div>
</div>
<?php

        foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $mykey=>$myvalues){
           echo '<div name="'.$myvalues[1].'" class="cat-title" id="'.$myvalues[0].'"><h2>'.$myvalues[1].'</h2></div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `name` attribute to an anchor tag, and then from another anchor tag, set the href to `#name`.

E.g.:

```
<a name='gohere'></a>
<a href='#gohere'>Click here to go to the named anchor tag</a>
```

Comment: @Litestone Good to know. I've never actually done this (never needed to), I just googled "link within a page" and summarized the first tutorial that popped up.

Comment: hmm, the code is fine, im just having trouble printing the name of the div  in anchor tag, im doing 
echo "<a href='".#$cat_name[1]."' class='cat-anchor'>"
and its not printing the variables value in the href

Comment: and one more thing, there is no need for jquery or javascript here?

Comment: `echo "<a href='#".$cat_name[1]."' class='cat-anchor'>";` and no, jquery nor javascript are required. It's a standard html function.

Comment: Man the solution is not working, the div has the name="Pizza" and the anchor have the href="#Pizza" but its not scrolling to that,let me write the code i'm trying.

Comment: Ah, in order to use a div, you need to use `id` rather than `name`. So either create an empty anchor tag right before the div with the name Pizza, or change the `name` attribute to `id` on the div.

Comment: ohhk, let me check if its previous giving id is not used anywhere else on the page

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this:

```
<div id="scrollToThisDiv"></div>
<a href="#scrollToThisDiv">GoToTheDiv</a>
```

You can animate the same using jQuery to give it a smoother effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="top"></div>
<a href="#home">go to home</a>
<div> some other contents
</div>
<div id="home">Home content Home content Home content Home content</div>
<a href="#top">scroll top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#clickhere">Go to Div</a>
.
.
.
<div id="clickhere">
Your Stuff
</div>
```

Add `ID` tag to where you wana go like the above `Div` tag and use an `Anchor` tag to point to that particular element.